# Generating a 96 or 384 well plate layout in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am trying to write some code which will take a .csv file which contains some sample names as input and will output a data.frame containing the sample names and either a 96 well plate or 384 well plate format (A1, B1, C1...). For those who do not know, a 96 well plate has eight alphabetically labeled rows (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) and 12 numerically labeled columns (1:12) and a 384 well plate has 16 alphabetically labeled rows (A:P) and 24 numerically labeled columns (1:24). I am trying to write some code that will generate either of these formats (there CAN be two different functions to do this) allowing for the samples to be labeled either DOWN (A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1, G1, H1, A2...) or ACROSS (A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 ...).

So far, I have figured out how to get the row names fairly easily

```
rowLetter <- rep(LETTERS[1:8], length.out = variable)
#variable will be based on how many samples I have
```

I just cannot figure out how to get the numeric column names to apply correctly... I have tried:

```
colNumber <- rep(1:12, times = variable)
```

but it isn't that simple. All 8 rows must be filled before the col number increases by 1 if you're going 'DOWN' or all 12 columns must be filled before the row letter increases by 1 if you're going 'ACROSS'.

EDIT:

Here is a clunky version. It takes the number of samples that you have, a 'plate format' which IS NOT functional yet, and a direction and will return a data.frame with the wells and plate numbers. Next, I am going to a) fix the plate format so that it will work correctly and b) give this function the ability to take a list of samples names or ID's or whatever and return the sample names, well positions, and plate numbers!

```
plateLayout <- function(numOfSamples, plateFormat = 96, direction = "DOWN"){
  #This assumes that each well will be filled in order. I may need to change this, but     lets get it working first.

  #Calculate the number of plates required
  platesRequired <- ceiling(numOfSamples/plateFormat)
  rowLetter <- character(0)
  colNumber <- numeric(0)
  plateNumber <- numeric(0)

  #The following will work if the samples are going DOWN
  if(direction == "DOWN"){
    for(k in 1:platesRequired){
     rowLetter <- c(rowLetter, rep(LETTERS[1:8], length.out = 96))  
      for(i in 1:12){
       colNumber <- c(colNumber, rep(i, times = 8))
      }
     plateNumber <- c(plateNumber, rep(k, times = 96))
    }  
  plateLayout <- paste0(rowLetter, colNumber)
  plateLayout <- data.frame(plateLayout, plateNumber)
  plateLayout <- plateLayout[1:numOfSamples,]
  return(plateLayout)
  }

  #The following will work if the samples are going ACROSS 
  if(direction == "ACROSS"){
    for(k in 1:platesRequired){
      colNumber <- c(colNumber, rep(1:12, times = 8))
      for(i in 1:8){
        rowLetter <- c(rowLetter, rep(LETTERS[i], times = 12))
        }
      plateNumber <- c(plateNumber, rep(k, times = 96))
      }
    plateLayout <- paste0(rowLetter, colNumber)
    plateLayout <- data.frame(plateLayout, plateNumber)
    plateLayout <- plateLayout[1:numOfSamples,]
    return(plateLayout)
  }
}
```

Does anybody have any thoughts on what else might make this cool? I'm going to use this function to generate .csv or .txt files to use as sample name imports for different instruments so I will be kind of constrained in terms of 'cool features', but I think it would be cool to use ggplot to make a graphic which shows the plates and sample names?

Comment: I believe you could simplify your function using the "each" and "times" parameters of the rep function: see my answer below.

Comment: As for cool features, the plot you suggest is nice (geom_tile comes to mind). Cool features could involve routines for doing block randomization within plates, define where standards are, etc. Have you done any extra work on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what I set out to do. You can use it to make as many plates as you need, with the assumptions that whatever your import list is will be in order. It can make as many plates as you need and will add a column for "plateNumber" which will indicate which batch it's on. It can only handle 96 or 384 well plates, but that is all I deal in so that is fine.

```
plateLayout <- function(numOfSamples, plateFormat = 96, direction = "DOWN"){
  #This assumes that each well will be filled in order.

#Calculate the number of plates required
platesRequired <- ceiling(numOfSamples/plateFormat)
rowLetter <- character(0)
colNumber <- numeric(0)
plateNumber <- numeric(0)

#define the number of columns and number of rows based on plate format (96 or 384 well plate)
switch(as.character(plateFormat),
       "96" = {numberOfColumns = 12; numberOfRows = 8},
       "384" = {numberOfColumns = 24; numberOfRows = 16})

#The following will work if the samples are going DOWN
if(direction == "DOWN"){
  for(k in 1:platesRequired){
    rowLetter <- c(rowLetter, rep(LETTERS[1:numberOfRows], length.out = plateFormat))  
  for(i in 1:numberOfColumns){
    colNumber <- c(colNumber, rep(i, times = numberOfRows))
    }
plateNumber <- c(plateNumber, rep(k, times = plateFormat))
  }  
plateLayout <- paste0(rowLetter, colNumber)
plateLayout <- data.frame(plateNumber,plateLayout)
plateLayout <- plateLayout[1:numOfSamples,]
return(plateLayout)
}

#The following will work if the samples are going ACROSS 
if(direction == "ACROSS"){
  for(k in 1:platesRequired){
    colNumber <- c(colNumber, rep(1:numberOfColumns, times = numberOfRows))
    for(i in 1:numberOfRows){
      rowLetter <- c(rowLetter, rep(LETTERS[i], times = numberOfColumns))
      }
    plateNumber <- c(plateNumber, rep(k, times = plateFormat))
    }
  plateLayout <- paste0(rowLetter, colNumber)
  plateLayout <- data.frame(plateNumber, plateLayout)
  plateLayout <- plateLayout[1:numOfSamples,]
  return(plateLayout)
  }
}
```

An example of how to use this would be as follows

```
#load whatever data you're going to use to get a plate layout on (sample ID's or names or whatever)
thisData <- read.csv("data.csv")

#make a data.frame containing your sample names and the function's output
    #alternatively you can use length() if you have a list
plateLayoutDataFrame <- data.frame(thisData$sampleNames, plateLayout(nrow(thisData), plateFormat = 96, direction = "DOWN")

#It will return something similar to the following, depending on your selections
#data plateNumber plateLayout
#sample1           1          A1
#sample2           1          B1
#sample3           1          C1
#sample4           1          D1
#sample5           1          E1
#sample6           1          F1
#sample7           1          G1
#sample8           1          H1
#sample9           1          A2
#sample10          1          B2
#sample11          1          C2
#sample12          1          D2
#sample13          1          E2
#sample14          1          F2
#sample15          1          G2
```

That sums up this function for now. Roland offered a good method of doing this which is less verbose, but I wanted to avoid the use of external packages if possible. I'm working on a `shiny` app now which actually uses this! I want it to be able to automatically subset based on the 'plateNumber' and write each plate as it's own file... for more on this, go to: [Automatic multi-file download in R-Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862151/automatic-multi-file-download-in-r-shiny)

Comment: "times = numberOfColumns" in the "ACROSS" block corrects typo in your code.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need `for` loops. Here is a start:

```
#some sample ids
ids <- c(LETTERS, letters)
#plate size:
n <- 96
nrow <- 8
samples <- character(n)
samples[seq_along(ids)] <- ids

samples <- matrix(samples, nrow=nrow)
colnames(samples) <- seq_len(n/nrow)
rownames(samples) <- LETTERS[seq_len(nrow)]

#   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  9  10 11 12
# A "A" "I" "Q" "Y" "g" "o" "w" "" "" "" "" ""
# B "B" "J" "R" "Z" "h" "p" "x" "" "" "" "" ""
# C "C" "K" "S" "a" "i" "q" "y" "" "" "" "" ""
# D "D" "L" "T" "b" "j" "r" "z" "" "" "" "" ""
# E "E" "M" "U" "c" "k" "s" ""  "" "" "" "" ""
# F "F" "N" "V" "d" "l" "t" ""  "" "" "" "" ""
# G "G" "O" "W" "e" "m" "u" ""  "" "" "" "" ""
# H "H" "P" "X" "f" "n" "v" ""  "" "" "" "" ""

library(reshape2)
samples <- melt(samples)
samples$position <- paste0(samples$Var1, samples$Var2)

#    Var1 Var2 value position
# 1     A    1     A       A1
# 2     B    1     B       B1
# 3     C    1     C       C1
# 4     D    1     D       D1
# 5     E    1     E       E1
# 6     F    1     F       F1
# 7     G    1     G       G1
# 8     H    1     H       H1
# 9     A    2     I       A2
# 10    B    2     J       B2
# 11    C    2     K       C2
# 12    D    2     L       D2
# 13    E    2     M       E2
# 14    F    2     N       F2
# 15    G    2     O       G2
# 16    H    2     P       H2
# 17    A    3     Q       A3
# 18    B    3     R       B3
# 19    C    3     S       C3
# 20    D    3     T       D3
# 21    E    3     U       E3
# 22    F    3     V       F3
# 23    G    3     W       G3
# 24    H    3     X       H3
# 25    A    4     Y       A4
# 26    B    4     Z       B4
# 27    C    4     a       C4
# 28    D    4     b       D4
# 29    E    4     c       E4
# 30    F    4     d       F4
# 31    G    4     e       G4
# 32    H    4     f       H4
# 33    A    5     g       A5
# 34    B    5     h       B5
# 35    C    5     i       C5
# 36    D    5     j       D5
# 37    E    5     k       E5
# 38    F    5     l       F5
# 39    G    5     m       G5
# 40    H    5     n       H5
# 41    A    6     o       A6
# 42    B    6     p       B6
# 43    C    6     q       C6
# 44    D    6     r       D6
# 45    E    6     s       E6
# 46    F    6     t       F6
# 47    G    6     u       G6
# 48    H    6     v       H6
# 49    A    7     w       A7
# 50    B    7     x       B7
# 51    C    7     y       C7
# 52    D    7     z       D7
# 53    E    7             E7
# 54    F    7             F7
# 55    G    7             G7
# 56    H    7             H7
# 57    A    8             A8
# 58    B    8             B8
# 59    C    8             C8
# 60    D    8             D8
# 61    E    8             E8
# 62    F    8             F8
# 63    G    8             G8
# 64    H    8             H8
# 65    A    9             A9
# 66    B    9             B9
# 67    C    9             C9
# 68    D    9             D9
# 69    E    9             E9
# 70    F    9             F9
# 71    G    9             G9
# 72    H    9             H9
# 73    A   10            A10
# 74    B   10            B10
# 75    C   10            C10
# 76    D   10            D10
# 77    E   10            E10
# 78    F   10            F10
# 79    G   10            G10
# 80    H   10            H10
# 81    A   11            A11
# 82    B   11            B11
# 83    C   11            C11
# 84    D   11            D11
# 85    E   11            E11
# 86    F   11            F11
# 87    G   11            G11
# 88    H   11            H11
# 89    A   12            A12
# 90    B   12            B12
# 91    C   12            C12
# 92    D   12            D12
# 93    E   12            E12
# 94    F   12            F12
# 95    G   12            G12
# 96    H   12            H12
```

Use the `byrow` argument to fill the matrix in the other direction:

```
samples <- matrix(samples, nrow=nrow, byrow=TRUE)
```

To fill more than one plate, you can use basically the same idea, but use an array instead of a matrix.

Comment: I'm a sucker for for-loops. Also, it hadn't occurred to me to use the reshape2 package, although this isn't a bad idea! However, I already have the function working well as a standalone. Give me a few minutes and I will post what I have and you can let me know what you think!

Comment: It is also possible to avoid for loops using the times and each parameters of the rep function. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

I've never written this code in R before but it should be the same as Perl, Python or Java

For Row major order (going across) the pseudocode algorithm is simply:

```
for each( i : 0..totalNumWells - 1){
   column   = (i % numColumns)
   row      = ((i % totalNumWells) / numColumns)
}
```

Where numColumns is 12 for 96 well plate, 24 or 384 and `totalNumWells` is 96 or 384 respectively.  This will give you a column and row index in 0-based coordinates which is perfect for accessing arrays.

```
 wellName   = ABCs[row], column + 1
```

Where ABCs is an array of all the valid letters in your plate (or A-Z).   `+1` is to convert 0-based into 1-based, otherwise the first well will be A0 instead of A1.

I also want to point out that often 384 wells aren't in row major order.  I've seen most often sequencing centers preferring a "checker board" pattern A01, A03, A05... then A02, A04, A06..., B01, B03... etc to be able to combine 4 96-well plates into a single 384 well without changing the layout and simplifying the picking robot's work.  that's a much harder algorithm to compute the ith well for

Comment: Thanks dkatzel. I am working on a more verbose answer which involves a) initially generating a full plate (A1:H12) and then subsetting out based on how many samples are needed and which direction the plate layout needs to be. I will post the code once I have it working!

This answer sort of worked, although I had to convert it to R. I tried posting the code in the comments but it was terribly formatted so I deleted it. It isn't generating the row numbers correctly for some reason. It's generating all zeros when I do

row <- ((i %% totalNumWells) / numColumns)

Comment: Also, I just realized that I need to code in an exception for the case when there are more samples than wells. In that case, I would get another plate (plate 1, plate 2...) and restart.

Comment: @JClarke09 your comment said "%%", I'm not sure what that does in R but it probably isn't modulus.  Also for plate overflows you can first do  i = i% 96 to convert i into a number from 1..95. Also just realized I said 1..96 when it should probably be 0..95. I'll update

Comment: `%%` is indeed the modulus operator in R. R's weird like that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Little late in the chain but the use of `expand.grid` can be very helpful. Also, I found that processing downstream sometimes benefits from being able to sort on the well name. The leading zeros in this example helps ensure that "A2" comes before "A10" in "A1", "A2"..."A10", "A11".

```
plateLayout <- function(nSamples, nPlates, plateFormat = c("96", "384"),
  direction = c("down", "across")) {

# process arguments
  nSamples <- as.integer(nSamples)
  plateFormat <- match.arg(plateFormat)
  plateFormat <- as.integer(plateFormat)
  direction <- match.arg(direction)
  nCol <- ifelse(plateFormat == 96, 12, 24)
  nRow <- ifelse(plateFormat == 96, 8, 16)
  if (missing(nPlates))
    nPlates <- ceiling(nSamples/plateFormat)
  
# use expand.grid and organize as 'plate', 'row' and 'column' 
  if (direction == "across") {
    v <- expand.grid(column = seq_len(nCol), row = LETTERS[1:nRow],
      plate = seq_len(nPlates), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    v <- v[c(3, 2, 1)]
  }
  else {
    v <- expand.grid(row = LETTERS[1:nRow], column = seq_len(nCol), 
      plate = seq_len(nPlates), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    v <- v[c(3, 1, 2)]
  }

# assemble data.frame
# note that the format string for sprintf provides a leading '0'
# change to "%s%d" to NOTuse a leading zero
  well <- apply(v, 1, function(x) sprintf("%s%02d", x[2], as.integer(x[3])))
  plate <- data.frame(plate = v[[1]], well)[seq_len(nSamples),]
  return(plate)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
put_samples_in_plates = function(sample_list, nwells=96, direction="across")
  {
  if(!nwells %in% c(96, 384)){
    stop("Invalid plate size")
  }
  nsamples = nrow(sample_list)
  nplates  = ceiling(nsamples/nwells);

  if(nwells==96){
    rows = LETTERS[1:8]
    cols = 1:12
  }else if(nwells==384){
    rows = LETTERS[1:16]
    cols = 1:24  
  }else{
    stop("Unrecognized nwells")
  }
  nrows = length(rows)
  ncols = length(cols)

  if(tolower(direction)=="down"){
    single_plate_df = data.frame(row = rep(rows, times=ncols), 
                                 col = rep(cols, each=nrows))    
  }else if(tolower(direction)=="across"){
    single_plate_df = data.frame(row = rep(rows, each=ncols), 
                                 col = rep(cols, times=nrows))    
  }else{
    stop("Unrecognized direction")
  }
  single_plate_df   = transform(single_plate_df, 
                                well = sprintf("%s%02d", row, col))  
  toobig_plate_df   = cbind(data.frame(plate=rep(1:nplates, each=nwells)), 
                            do.call("rbind", replicate(nplates, 
                                                       single_plate_df, 
                                                       simplify=FALSE)))
  res = cbind(sample_list, toobig_plate_df[1:nsamples,])
  return(res)}

# Quick test

a_sample_list = data.frame(x=1:386, y=rnorm(386))

r.096.across = put_samples_in_plates(sample_list = a_sample_list,
                                     nwells= 96, 
                                     direction="across")
r.096.down   = put_samples_in_plates(sample_list = a_sample_list,
                                     nwells= 96, 
                                     direction="down")
r.384.across = put_samples_in_plates(sample_list = a_sample_list,
                                     nwells=384, 
                                     direction="across")
r.384.down   = put_samples_in_plates(sample_list = a_sample_list,
                                     nwells=384, 
                                     direction="down")
```

Two points worth noting in the function above:

- the use of the times and each parameters within the rep function to differentiate "across" and "down" directions, and
- the use of replicate to repeat the individual plate as many times as needed along with the use of a call to rbind from do.call.