# Automatic multi-file download in R-Shiny

Tags: r, bioinformatics, shiny

I'm trying to figure out how to get a `data.frame` to subset itself and then write a .csv file for each subset. I'm writing a `shiny` app which will generate template files for different instruments, and I need to be able to get a file for each batch/plate/whatever. Obviously, we could do a manual sort, but that kind of defeats the purpose.

In example, say that I have a `data.frame` with 4 columns named 1) PlateID, 2) SampleName, 3) Well and 4) Comments and I want to subset by the PlateID such that each individual plate will have it's own file.

```
output$multiDownload <- renderText({
#templateData() just loads the data, nothing special;
#If you wanna see it let me know, but I think it's bulky
  tempData <- templateData()
  if(is.null(tempData)){return(NULL)}

    #If there are more than one plate, subset by plate ID and write each file
    if(max(tempData$PlateID) > 1){
    for(i in 1:max(tempData$PlateID)){
        tempSubsetForWrite <- subset(tempData, tempData$PlateID == i, select =   c("names", "well", "comments"))
        write.csv(tempSubsetForWrite, file = paste0("file ", i, " of ", max(tempData$PlateID), row.names = FALSE)
      }
  } else {
    write.csv(tempData, file = "file", row.names = FALSE)
  }
})
```

So I want to add a few features and I'm not sure how to approach them. First, I would like to have better control of where the data is written. I would like it to go into the same file as my input files, but I'm not sure how to force this? I tried doing something like:

```
inFile <- input$templateGenerationFile
write.csv(tempData, paste0(inFile$datapath, "/file ", i, " of ", max(tempData$PlateID))
```

but in `inFile$datapath` appears to be a temp folder/file which is generated and not a direct link to the original file!

Also, I'm wanting to write something that will act like a `downloadHandler` in the sense of having a button which will download the files upon clicking, but I don't think I can use that in this scenario because I am writing multiple files. If I'm wrong then PLEASE let me know, as that would make life easier. I am thinking that I will use an `actionButton` and a counter variable so that the counter is the value of the button + 1 until the button is activated, in which case they are equal until the end of the function. Obviously I would have a conditional which handles the rest, but that is trivial so lets focus on the file subset and download!

Thanks!

Comment: `inFile$datapath` must be a temp file; because the data was uploaded via a browser, the original file path is gone. Web browsers don't tell web servers what the full file path on the client was, because it's generally expected that the browser and server are running on different machines so what good is a full file path? If this app is only designed to work locally, then you could maybe try `file.choose()` tied to an `actionButton()` instead.

Comment: As for your original question, how about a `downloadHandler` that writes a .zip file that contains multiple .csv files?

Comment: Thanks Joe! I'm not sure if I'm going to host it on a server or use it locally yet. 

Hmm. That is an interesting idea! I haven't ever done that before, but I will look into it. Google, here we come!

Comment: Joe, I have looked into the `zip()` function and it appears that you pass filepaths to the `file` argument, implying that the files already have to exist. I'm investigating a workaround; My first thought would be to write a function or loop that will subset and iterate over itself multiple times for each 'batch' and see if I cannot just create temp files to zip. I'm not sure if this will work exactly how I want, but it would definitely be more manageable than some of the alternatives, and I could still tie it to a `downloadHandler`. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry JClarke09, I just saw this. Yeah I was just thinking you would create the files in a temp dir, zip them, and then delete the temporary files you created.

Comment: Did you ever get zip downloads to work?

Answer (score 3):

The `zip()` doesn't work for me but it is easy with the `tar` function..

```
      output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
         filename = function() { paste("filesintar", '.tar', sep='') },
         content = function(file) {
           tar(file,"./dirwheremyfilesare") #  no inlcuye rutas hasta raíz.
         }
       )
```

hope this will help.
I try with `zip` instead of `tar` but I've got an error :

```
        zip(file, paste("./dirwheremyfilesare/",dir("./dirwheremyfilesare"),sep=""))
```

Thank u.

Antonio M.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that, but I'm still not sure how to handle the multiple files and the subsetting. :) I will experiment with this concept though!

Comment: I still haven't tried this. I will try to get to it today so that if it works I can give you the answer check mark!

Answer (score 1):

I modified @amaurandi answer to complete OP question, adding some extra decorations that I found worked for me. Warning, I also used a `plyr` function, `dlply`, to simplify a bit.

I reproduced the problem with `zip` throwing an error (cannot explain it), but `tar` can be made to work. In principle these are platform independent functions in R, but that also implies everything is setup correctly with your installation.

Example based on OP starting point and previous answer snippet from @amaurandi

```r
output$multiDownload <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function(){
    # Time-stamp tar filename
    paste0("platetables-", gsub("\\D", "_", Sys.time()), ".tar")
  },
  content = function(file){
    # Loads the data. Could be reactive.
    tempData <- templateData()
    if(is.null(tempData)){
      # Protect against empty data.
      return(NULL)
    }
    plateNames = unique(tempData$PlateID)
    tempdir = tempdir()
    dlist = plyr::dlply(tempData, "PlateID", function(x) x[, c("names", "well", "comments")])
    for(i in plateNames){
      write.csv(x = dlist[[i]], file = paste0(tempdir, "/", i, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
    }
    tar(tarfile = file, files = tempdir)
  }
)
```